# How can I search for all of the usage of one text in GoLand(It is a text, not a function or something)

Tags: go, settings, goland

When I read a great program today, I wanted to find out all of the usage of one text in `fmt.Println()`, but I didn't know how to do that in GoLand.
We can use "⌥ ⌘ F7" to search for some functions or other things. `fmt.Println()` for example.

[image: picture of finding the function fmt.Println()]

But I can't do it when I want to find the text in `fmt.Println()`
[image: The situation when I search for the text]

But I can search the text in VsCode
[image: When I search it in VsCode]

So, what's the problem? I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find a particular string anywhere in a project, consider using ["Find in Files"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html). You might want to narrow your search using file masks and filters like "In string literals" filter and `.*go` file mask.

[image: Find in Files filters]

If you are looking for a string in a particular file, use ["Find"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html).

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, "⌥ ⌘ F6" is used for finding the function, and this file tells me how to find another thing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can search by using global search:

Mac: `⌥ ⌘ F`

Windows: `Ctrl+Shift+F`